# Laravel Eloquent sql statement after exist check is limited to 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've found a really weird behaviour in the current laravel 4.2 patch. Until now whenever I want to get some datas from my eloquent model I check if results are available before i get them via the following code example:

```
$foo = $model->hasManyRelationFunction();
if($foo->exists())
  foreach($foo->get() as $elem) 
     ....
```

this results in the following sql statement:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from "vendor_tabs" where "vendor_tabs"."vendor_id" = '80' limit 1 <-- exist() ?
```

following by the real select sql statement without Limit 1, for example:

`select * from "vendor_tabs" where "vendor_tabs"."vendor_id" = '80' order by "id" asc`

Since i've updated laravel 4.2 to the current patch, it also limits the real sql statement to 1

```
`select * from "vendor_tabs" where "vendor_tabs"."vendor_id" = '80' order by "id" asc` limit 1
```

but ONLY when I make the `if($foo->exists())` check. As soon i comment out the exist condition everything works fine. Are their any informations about this behaviour or am I just stupid? :D

Edit: It seems like they made the eloquent builder "more fluent" in patch 4.2.13. I still dont know if this is a bug or a feature, imo this shouldnt be the normal behaviour.

```
/**
 * Determine if any rows exist for the current query.
 *
 * @return bool
 */


public function exists()
    {
        $limit = $this->limit;

        $result = $this->limit(1)->count() > 0;

        $this->limit($limit);

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: I was just looking in to this... I believe the `limit()` method has a bug. The limit method only sets `$this->limit` if the limit sent through is greater than 0. Which neither 0 nor null are.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need to check existence. You should only do:

```
foreach ($model->hasManyRelationFunction as $elem) {
  // do whathever you want
}
```

and it's just enough to get the data. You don't need to check existence here or if you think you do, you should show a real example of a code what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well that's true, but doesn't really answer the question why the OPs code isn't working correctly...

Comment: Well, in that case i may could just iterate the resultset without the existence check. But imagine if you want to get a specific property of the first row before you foreach the (whole) resultset you would get a "Trying to access a property of a non-object" eception if you dont check for existence. Furthermore a pure check for existence shouldn't affect the sql statement by itself. That's the opposite of intuitive programming